# Handling Individual Statuses for Recurring Tasks in RRule: Strategies and RFC 5545 Compliance

Tags: icalendar, rrule, rfc5545

**Problem:**
I am working with recurring tasks (RRules) and need a way to manage individual statuses for each generated instance without affecting the overall recurrence pattern. Specifically, I want to be able to mark a single instance of a recurring task as complete while leaving the rest untouched.

**What I've Tried:**
I am considering implementing two mechanisms:

**Removing, then Recreating Instances:** For any instance that is not the immediate next one in the series, I remove it from the original item and create a new individual item with the same attributes but a different status. For example, if I complete tomorrow's task ahead of today's, I would extract it and treat it separately.

**Removing, then Shifting the Original Item:** When marking the immediate next instance as complete (e.g., today's task), I would create a new individual item with the updated status and then recreate the original item starting from the subsequent instance (e.g., from tomorrow).

Additionally, I plan to use a custom property on the original item to track these individual status changes, allowing me to construct a global status for the item.

Is there a more elegant or RFC 5545 native way to handle individual statuses for recurring tasks in RRule? I am looking for solutions that are both effective and adhere to established standards. I hope I can find a way to efficiently manage individual statuses without overly complicating the recurrence logic.